# How can I subtract the values in one row from the values in another row in the same mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query in a php file:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    a.aurl as al,
    (a.lttotals 
       - 
       ( SELECT b.lttotals 
         FROM stats b 
         WHERE ltdate='$newdate'
         AND b.aurl=a.aurl
       )
    ) as tt,
    lttotals
 FROM stats a 
 WHERE ltdate='$date'
 ORDER BY lttotals DESC 
 LIMIT 20";
```

This is very slow and if I change the limit to more than 20 mysql goes away. ;)

Basically what I need to do is to take the values from certain columns in one row and subtract them from another row.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do using what I have now or should I restructure how I store my data?

Comment: Have you considered a self-join instead of a subquery?Those usually perform better. Also, what happens if more than two rows in the table have the same aurl value?

Comment: Have a look here for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6910199/27535 How many rows are involved) How do you pair rows? Sample data too please...

Comment: Is `(aurl, ltdate)` a unique combination in your table? You query may fail if it's not.

Comment: I have a very basic knowledge of what I'm doing. I'll go read up on self-join. There are over 500,000 rows in the table and I add about 15,000 rows a week. There are definitely duplicate aurl's but that is the nature of the data. I will gather sample data and a better table structure and post back here after reading more about self-join and reading the link posted above. thank you so much for the help so far.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to make this work much better using a self-join suggested by JohnFx and information I got from the link posted by gbn. While it still takes a little while to run the query (I'll look into the solution for indexes suggested below) it actually is more accurate as well as a tiny bit quicker. The final query is: SELECT a.aurl, a.lttotals, a.ltdate, (a.lttotals-b.lttotals) as tt FROM stats AS a, stats AS b WHERE a.aurl = b.aurl AND a.ltdate = '$date' AND b.ltdate = '$newdate' ORDER BY tt desc limit 30

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.aurl AS a1,
        a.lttotals
        a.lttotals - b.lttotals
FROM    stats a
JOIN    stats b
ON      b.aurl = a.aurl
        AND b.ltdate = '$newdate'
WHERE   a.ltdate = '$date'
ORDER BY
        a.lttotals DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Create the following indexes:

```
stats (ltdate, lttotals)
stats (ltdate, aurl)
```

for this to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.url AS al,
   (a.lttotals - b.lttotals) AS tt,
   a.lttotals
FROM stats a, stats b
WHERE a.ltdate='$date' AND b.ltdate='$newdate' AND a.url = b.url
ORDER BY a.lttotals DESC
```